# Vim: how to restore the cursor's logical and physical positions?

Tags: vim

How to restore the cursor's "logical" and "physical" positions when I open a file ?

That's:

1. the cursor should be on the last-time logical line in the file.
2. the cursor should be on the last-time physical line according to the vim window

I've notice [this post](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session). It does put the cursor on the right logical line. But the cursor physical position in the window is the first line or the middle.

**UPDATE**:
The solution is `mkview` and `loadview` as noted by @sehe.

To make it work with other plugins (in my case, latex file + [latex-box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box)), the following would be useful:

`au BufWinLeave *.tex mkview`

`au VimEnter *.tex loadview`

From the Vim documentation of `VimEnter`:

- After doing all the startup stuff, including loading `.vimrc` files, executing the "-c cmd" arguments, creating all windows and loading the buffers in them.

**UPDATE2**:  To better orginize the "view-snapshot-files"

By creating a folder `~/.vim/view`, you will keep all the "view-snapshot-files" there.

If you are using `git` to synchronize `~/.vim` across computers, maybe you'd like to

- ignore the files in `~/.vim/view`,
- but keep the empty folder in your repo.

Then you need to (addapted according to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository))

- create a empty file: `~/.vim/view/.gitignore`
- put `view/*`, and `!.gitignore`  in `~/.vim/.gitignore`

Comment: Another way of stating your second requirement is that the top line of the window should be the same as well. (If possible! Consider the case where the cursor was on the last line of the screen, then you open the file again in a smaller window.) I don't think this is something that `viminfo` will do, but it would be possible with some scripting/autocommands.

Comment: Thanks @Jefromi. Maybe you are right. It's not possible. (I did expect some settings of viminfo and some short functions in vimrc, though I know the plugin session does this.)

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible! Just not a quick built-in thing.

Comment: @Jefromi: I think it is possible **and** built-in. See my answer

Comment: @sehe: Ah, cool. It does still require autocommands (i.e. isn't just flipping a "restore position" config switch) but I didn't realize it would be that simple!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Good news, `:mkview` already has this (see documentation excerpt below).

Most specifically `:loadview` restores scroll position, as well as folding state, if `viewoptions` includes `cursor,folds`.

The even better news is, that you can transparently enable views for all opened files if you wish to. E.g. to enable view saving for all C source-files, add this to $MYVIMRC:

```
au BufWinLeave *.c mkview
au BufWinEnter *.c silent loadview
```

**Edit** As per Hongying's comments, in combination with certain plugins, it might work better if you used the `VimEnter` auto command for loading the view.

Optionally use the `viewdir` option to define the location for saved views.

*Be sure to also look at **`:mksession`** because it is even more powerful, in that it can restore multiple windows, tabs and their positions, mappings, registers, options, fold state etc. etc.*

#### How it works

Vim `:mkview` saves ex commands to restore the location like the following:

```
silent! normal! zE
let s:l = 88 - ((4 * winheight(0) + 4) / 9)
if s:l < 1 | let s:l = 1 | endif
exe s:l
normal! zt
88
normal! 025l
```

`:loadview` just sources those commands, like any vimscript.

#### From the docs

**Note** This is *clipped* from the docs, be sure the read more doing `he :mkview`

```
                            *:mkvie* *:mkview*
:mkvie[w][!] [file] Write a Vim script that restores the contents of the
            current window.
            When [!] is included an existing file is overwritten.
            When [file] is omitted or is a number from 1 to 9, a
            name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended.  When the
            last directory name in 'viewdir' does not exist, this
            directory is created.
            An existing file is always overwritten then.  Use
            |:loadview| to load this view again.
            When [file] is the name of a file ('viewdir' is not
            used), a command to edit the file is added to the
            generated file.

The output of ":mkview" contains these items:
1. The argument list used in the window.  When the global argument list is
   used it is reset to the global list.
   The index in the argument list is also restored.
2. The file being edited in the window.  If there is no file, the window is
   made empty.
3. Restore mappings, abbreviations and options local to the window if
   'viewoptions' contains "options" or "localoptions".  For the options it
   restores only values that are local to the current buffer and values local
   to the window.
   When storing the view as part of a session and "options" is in
   'sessionoptions', global values for local options will be stored too.
4. Restore folds when using manual folding and 'viewoptions' contains
   "folds".  Restore manually opened and closed folds.
5. The scroll position and the cursor position in the file.  Doesn't work very
   well when there are closed folds.
6. The local current directory, if it is different from the global current
   directory.
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you! @sehe. It works well if I type the commands myself, but it still puts the cursor on the first line of the window. Do you notice that? ( I've tested this for tex file. And in my .vimrc I've added "au BufWinLeave *.tex mkview
au BufWinEnter *.tex silent loadview
" )

Comment: It was because other latex-plugins.

Comment: how can I run "loadview" after other tex-plugins ? (If it matters: I'm using latex-box.)

Comment: @Hongying: I really don't know. But by looking at the view-files you can see that latex might be 'undoing' things in the `SessionLoadPost` autocommand, which is triggered at the end. In general, try using `noautocmd loadview`. There is no guarantee though; You can use `:verbose autocmd` and `:debug ...` to find out what gets triggered from where (and where the `autocmd`s are last defined). Oh, and just in case a _latex_ plugin is clobbering the cursor position by a motion command, see if hitting '``' gets you back where you wanted

Comment: I find a solution: put "au BufWinLeave *.tex mkview
and 
au VimEnter *.tex loadview" instead.