# Open file with :tag and jump to last edited position

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

When using `ctags` with Vim, it's possible to open a file as:

```
:tag <filename>
```

This is possible if the `tags` file was generated using the `--extras=+qf` flag, like in this code snippet:

```sh
$ find . -name "*.c" | xargs ctags-universal --extras=+qf -L -
```

This produces a line in the tags file such as this:

```
JPEGImageDecoder.cpp Source/WebCore/platform/image-decoders/jpeg/JPEGImageDecoder.cpp  1;"   F
```

This entry contains 4 elements: {tag name, path to file, line number, tag type}. Whenever Vim opens the tag, it goes to line number 1, despite I have configured Vim to remember the last edited position of a file and go back to it when the buffer is read.

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
endif
```

Is there any way of opening a file with `:tag <filename>` and set the cursor to the last edited position?

Comment: The builtin functions `winsaveview` and `winrestview` can save and restore the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact duplicate, but see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8854371/8812461).

I'm not sure if you could do it with the `:tag` command. Consider making your own `:Tag` command that accomplishes this, maybe something like:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
command -nargs=? Tag :tag <args> | loadview
```

This is essentially copypasta from the aforementioned thread. Make sure you also see `:mksession`; it's even more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

In Vim, `:help tags-file-format` shows information about a ctags entry format:

```
The lines in the tags file must have one of these three formats:

1.  {tagname}           {TAB} {tagfile} {TAB} {tagaddress}
2.  {tagfile}:{tagname} {TAB} {tagfile} {TAB} {tagaddress}
3.  {tagname}           {TAB} {tagfile} {TAB} {tagaddress} {term} {field} ..
```

Somewhere below, it states the following about `{tagaddress}`:

```
{tagaddress}    The Ex command that positions the cursor on the tag.  It can
                be any Ex command, although restrictions apply (see
                tag-security).  Posix only allows line numbers and search
                commands, which are mostly used.
```

In most cases this `{tagaddress}` is a line number or a regular expression, but it should be possible to use other Vim mechanisms for positioning the cursor. If I replace `1` for `'"` (last edited position), it works.

So basically I need to produce a tags file that, for the indexed filenames, replaces the default `1` for `'"`. Ideally that should be an argument in `exuberant-ctags` or `universal-ctags`, but basically I did that by postprocessing the tags file with `sed`:

```sh
# Replace 1 for "' (first line for last edited line).
sed -ri "s/1;\"\s+F$/'\";\"\tF/" .tags
```