# How to have vim give the command line parameter +<lnum> precedence over 'au VimEnter *? silent loadview'?

Tags: vim, parameters

I successfully applied the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8857441/) to this question:
[Vim: how to restore the cursor's logical and physical positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854371/vim-how-to-restore-the-cursors-logical-and-physical-positions)

However, the above solution appears to override `+<lnum>` passed on the command line.
How can I have vim give the command line precedence over this entry in _vimrc:

```
au BufWinLeave *? mkview
au VimEnter *? silent loadview
```

Answer (score 2):

From `:help VimEnter`, emphasis mine:

> **After** doing all the startup stuff, including loading .vimrc files, **executing the "-c cmd" arguments**, creating all windows and loading the buffers in them.

Since the `VimEnter` event is triggered *after* `+<lnum>`, autocommands bound to that event will always be executed *after* `+<lnum>`.

From there, you have two paths…

- use another autocommand in your command-line argument:

  ```
  $ vimfilename +au\ VimEnter\ *\ 34
  ```
- find a more appropriate event.